# How to install Angular and Nodejs in the same folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I am new to `NodeJs` and `Angular` and I have created simple Nodejs application using [this link](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-backend-express) but there was no example on how to install Angular alongside Nodejs. I tried running `ng new angular-crud` in the root folder and it created `angular-crud` folder within the `root` folder. Now I have 2 node_modules folder, first in `root` folder and second in `angular-crud` folder.

a) **INSTALL** ::How to install Angular so that there is always only one node_modules folder.

b) **RUN** ::Nodejs application is run using command `node app.js` where `app.js` is the `entry point` but on the other hand Angular application is run using `ng serve`. 
If I have both the Nodejs and Angular installed then how to run the application.

c) **STRUCTURE**:: What should be the ideal folder structure when using Node and Angular together.

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "test-na",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3"
  },
  "description": "test",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

My app.js file:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://example.com',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
};

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors(corsOptions));


app.route('/api/cats').get((req, res) => {
    res.send({
        cats: [{ name: 'lilly' }, { name: 'lucy' }]
    });
});

app.route('/api/cats').post((req, res) => {
    res.send(201, req.body);
});

app.route('/api/cats/:name').get((req, res) => {
    const requestedCatName = req.params['name'];
    res.send({ name: requestedCatName });
});

app.route('/api/cats/:name').put((req, res) => {
    res.send(200, req.body);
});

app.route('/api/cats/:name').delete((req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(204);
});

app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log('Server started');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular is intended to create single page applications: if you **won't perform server side rendering**, you probably shouldn't embed an Angular application within a nodeJs application.

Instead, the Angular application should live in its own folder (and, usually, in its own server), and connect with the nodeJs application by firing API calls.

For instance, you could have the domain https://acme.com to serve the Angular application **statically**, and your Angular application will perform api requests against https://acme.com/api/v1/.

Unless you need [server side rendering](https://angular.io/guide/universal) (I don't know almost anything about Angular SSR), there is probably nothing you will gain by embed Angular within the nodeJs app. [If you follow the Angular deploy guide](https://angular.io/guide/deployment), you will see that the intended form to serve and deploy Angular apps is to serve the Angular app statically from an Apache or Ngnx.

Answer (score 2):

Put client and server code separated into two independent directories.

[**Here's a good article for these issues.**](https://medium.com/@tsmith18256/creating-a-mean-stack-with-angular-2-and-typescript-3dd23b3e717f)

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple, first create new angular project using angular cli or you can also clone already existing angular project. Then add folder named **server**, this will contain all your node server files. Let the app.js file be saved in the root (outside the server folder)

Your Folder Structure will be like the following:

```
e2e            
src           
server        
node_modules    
karma.conf.js  
package.json  
tslint.json  
tsconfig.json  
protracter.conf.js  
README.md  
app.js
```

You can then add required dependencies (like express, body-parser) of node server to the package.json

**To serve angular through node server**
Add the following line to the app.js file, dist folder will be your build folder, which will be created when you do **ng build**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes in app.js as shown below. And also, angular-cli should be installed. And then run the following commands:

1. ng build (dist folder will get generated automatically)
2. node app

Your app.js file should look like the following

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();


// Parsers
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

// Angular DIST output folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Send all other requests to the Angular app
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

//Set Port
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on localhost:${port}`));
```